# Identify and internal direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I have to proof this proposition. 
I found a proof to the proposition in a textbook. 
But there are some things that I don't understand in the proof. 
Bold text in the proof are my questions. 
I have to show a detailed proof.

Proposition:
Let $U$ and $W$ be vector spaces and $V= U \oplus W$. 
Then $V$ has subspaces $U'$ and $W'$ such that we can identify $U'$ with $U$, $W'$ with $W$ and such that $V$ is the internal direct sum of $U'$ and $W'$.

Proof: 
We define $U'=\{(u,0) \mid u \in U \}$ and $W'=\{(0,w) \mid w \in W\}$ and claim that these satisfy the things claimed.

**Can we define $U'$ and $W'$ in other ways? 
If we can why is it smart to define $U'$ and $W'$ like this? 
Which claims do $U'$ and $W'$ exactly have to claim?**

First, we can identify $U'$ with $U$ by the map $ U' \rightarrow U$ given $(u,0) \rightarrow u$ and similarly for $W'$ and $W$.

**As I understand identify $U'$ with $U$ means that $U$ and $U'$ are isomorphic, right? 
Do we claim that $U$ and $U'$ are from the same field and that's why we can make a map from $U'$ to $U$? 
By defining a map how do show that we can identify $U'$ with $U$?**

Second, any element $v=(u,w) \in V$ can by definition be written as $(u,0)+(0,w) \in U +W$. 
Finally, if $x \in U\cap W$ then by definition we have $z=(0,0)=0$.

**We have to show that $V$ is internal direct sum of $U'$ and $W'$ then why does we show that  $(u,0)+(0,w) \in U +W$  and $x \in U\cap W$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we define $U'$ and $W'$ in other ways?

Maybe?  If you want to do it a harder, less obvious way, I think the burden is on you to explain why one should spend time doing that, though.

> If we can why is it smart to define $U'$ and $W'$ like this?

The reason for choosing this way is because it makes verification of the internal direct sum trivial.

> Which claims do $U'$ and $W'$ exactly have to claim?

The usual definition of “$V=U’\oplus W’$” is “$U’$ and $W’$ are subspaces such that $U’+W’=V$ and $U’\cap W’=\{0\}$.”

> As I understand identify $U'$ with $U$ means that $U$ and $U'$ are isomorphic, right?

Yes.

> Do we claim that $U$ and $U'$ are from the same field and that's why we can make a map from $U'$ to $U$?

If you mean that they are vector spaces over the same field, then yes, that is true.

> By defining a map how do show that we can identify $U'$ with $U$?

$x\mapsto ( x,0)$ is an isomorphism of $U$ with $U’$.

> We have to show that $V$ is internal direct sum of $U'$ and $W'$ then why does we show that  $(u,0)+(0,w) \in U +W$  and $x \in U\cap W$?

I guess you mean $U’$ and $W’$ everywhere because $U$ and $W$ aren’t, a priori, subsets of anything that you could add or intersect.   But after that correction, you would have to verify these things because that is the usual definition of direct sum.

Some of this explanation could change of course if you mention any background you have left out. I am only answering using the most common interpretation of the limited information given .